# unexpected gfortran compiling error

Tags: fortran

Recently, I started to lean fortran programming. I have seen the following code at youtube without any error it is compiled. But I have got some errors. 
I appreciate any help

```
program 
  implicit none
  real, parameter :: pi=4*atan(1.0) 
  integer, parameter :: n = 100
  real :: dimension(1:n) :: x, y
  real :: a=0.0, b = 2*pi
  real :: increment
  integer :: i  

  increment = (b-a)/(real(n)-1) 

  x(1)=0.0
  do i =2,n
    x(i) = x(i-1) + increment
  end do

  y = sin(x)

  print *, x(1:5)
  print *, y(1:5)

end program
```

Comment: "Some errors" can be solved by "some solutions". Be more specific.

Comment: And be specific about which version of gfortran you are using.

Answer (score 4):

`real :: dimension(1:n) :: x, y` is a syntax error.   Replace the first `::` with a comma.  You may need to give a name on the program statement.

Answer (score 1):

You also have mixed-mode arithmetic in line

`increment = (b-a)/(real(n)-1)`

It will probably compile, and it may not even affect the program, but you should never, never have mixed-mode arithmetic in any programming language as it can cause strange, hard to find bugs.
It should look like this:

`increment = (b-a)/(real(n)-1.0)`

Comment: I do not believe it is an issue for such simple constants. The compiler will do the conversion in a straightforward way.

Comment: Mixed-mode arithmetic is well defined by the standard and should not be compiler dependent - see section 7.1.5.1 and Table 7.2 of the 2008 standard. Additional verbosity here is redundant and `(b-a)/(n-1)` yields the expected result, as both `a` and `b` are `real`. Of course, here I am assuming that the programmer is familiar with the rules of mixed-mode arithmetic. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the results of a working example which addresses the concerns of @High Performance Mark.

```
host system       = (redacted)
compiler version  = GCC version 5.1.0
compiler options  = -fPIC -mmacosx-version-min=10.9.4 -mtune=core2 -Og -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wpedantic -fmax-errors=5
execution command = ./a.out

 Compare mesh points
   1.57017982       1.57080817       1.57143652    
   1.57016802       1.57079625       1.57142460    
 Compare function values at these mesh points
   1622.04211      -84420.7344      -1562.01758    
   1591.57471       13245402.0      -1591.65527
```

There is a bad programming practice in the demo you found: moving through the mesh by adding steps (+ increment) instead of counting them (k * increment). The problem is widespread and appears with severe consequences (https://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold/disasters/patriot.html).

For demonstration on your code, the size of the mesh was boosted to 10K points. Also the sample function changed from `cos x` to `tan x` and we examine points near the singularity at pi/2 = 1.57079633. While the novitiate may find the discrepancies in mesh values trivial, the difference in function values is significant.

(Mesh errors can be reduced by using increments which have exact binary representation like 2^(-13) = 1 / 8192.)

The code is shown here. The compilation command is `gfortran  -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Og -pedantic  -fmax-errors=5 demo.f95`. The run command is `./a.out`.

```
program demo
    use iso_fortran_env
    implicit none

    real,    parameter :: pi = acos ( -1.0 ) 
    integer, parameter :: n = 10001

    real, dimension ( 1 : n ) :: x, y, z
    real                      :: a = 0.0, b = 2 * pi
    real                      :: increment

    integer :: k, quarter, status

    character ( len = * ), parameter :: c_options = compiler_options( )
    character ( len = * ), parameter :: c_version = compiler_version( )
    character ( len = 255 )          :: host = " ", cmd = " "

!       queries
        call hostnm      ( host, status )
        call get_command ( cmd )

!       write identifiers
        write ( *, '( /, "host system       = ", g0    )' ) trim ( host )
        write ( *, '(    "compiler version  = ", g0    )' ) c_version
        write ( *, '(    "compiler options  = ", g0    )' ) trim ( c_options )
        write ( *, '(    "execution command = ", g0, / )' ) trim ( cmd )

        increment = ( b - a ) / ( n - 1 )
        quarter = n / 4

!       mesh accumulates errors
        x ( 1 ) = 0.0
        do k = 2, n
            x ( k ) = x ( k - 1 ) + increment
        end do
        y = tan ( x )

        print *, 'Compare mesh points'
        print *, x ( quarter : quarter + 2 )

!       better mesh
        x ( 1 ) = 0.0
        do k = 2, n
            x ( k ) = ( k - 1 ) * increment
        end do
        z = tan ( x )
        print *, x ( quarter : quarter + 2 )

        print *, 'Compare function values at these mesh points'
        print *, y ( quarter : quarter + 2 )
        print *, z ( quarter : quarter + 2 )

end program demo
```